# Learning WardrobeCMS source code, how do they retrieve posts without db request?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Newbie here. I'm learning Laravel and WardrobeCMS is a good one to study IMO. Just wondering if you guys could point me how they retrieve posts with requesting db?

In homepage, the *HomeController* has this line.

```
$posts = $this->posts->active(Config::get('core::wardrobe.per_page'));
```

In *WardrobeServiceProvider*, they bind *PostRepoitory* with *DbPostRepository* and here is their 'active' method.

```
public function active($per_page)
{
    $per_page = is_numeric($per_page) ? $per_page : 5;

    \Debugbar::info('calling posts active method');

    return Post::with(array('tags', 'user'))
        ->where('active', 1)
        ->where('publish_date', '<=', new DateTime)
        ->orderBy('publish_date', 'desc')
        ->paginate($per_page);
}
```

The return statement looks like the Eloquent command but **I don't see any db request in Debugbar console**. How does this work? Please advise.

I am a designer trying to learn coding and Laravel 'illuminates' me. In my current dev project, I have around 4-10 db calls in each page. My goal here is to reduce db calls as much as possible and I think WardrobeCMS source code is my starting point.

Comment: It's `Eloquent` model that is doing the query, check the [manual](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) first.

Comment: Hi Sheikh! Thanks for replying. I'm following your blog! As you might have guessed, i'm a newbie here. I think I know Eloquent model only a bit after trying to study from source code and am wondering if the query like Post::with()->where()->paginate(); doesn't always 'call' database? Obviously I'm missing something here. Could you give me some advise what kind of data source that query retrieves? A cache perhaps?

Comment: Its retrieving the data from database, Eloquent is an `ORM` and `Post` in this example is an `Eloquent ORM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post::with()->where()->paginate(); doesn't always 'call' database?
```

**In short: Yes it does!**

`Post` is an `Eloquent` [ORM](http://www.slideshare.net/rob_knight/object-relational-mapping-in-php) because, basically every model (i.e. `Post`) in `Laravel` extends the `Eloquent`/`Model` class and this `Eloquent`/`Model` class uses `Query Builder` (`DB` in your case) class along with other classes to query the database and in your example, the `Post` is something like this:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {
    // ...
}
```

SInce the `Post` class extends the `Eloquent` class so `Post` have access (inherited from Eloquent) to all (protected and public only) methods of `Eloquent` class, so, if the `Eloquent` has a function/method like this (actually has):

```
public function with($relation)
{
    //...
}
```

Then the `Post` class can call that function/method like this:

```
Post::with()
```

So, actually `Post::with()->where()->paginate()` call interact with `database` in this case but it's not necessary that every database interaction has to be using `DB::table()`, instead, it's a convenient way to query the database using an `ORM` and don't forget that, the `ORM` is just a wrapper over the query builder, behind the scene, the `Post Eloquent Model` is using the query builder.

You should the manual instead of reading the source code of another application, once you get the basic idea then you may read source code of other Laravel applications to get some ideas that other developers uses.

**Update:** If you are not seeing any queries in the debugger then the application is using the [caching feature of Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/cache) to cache database queries for a certain period of time so it can use those later without interacting with the database to speed up the process.